# Complex for loop c# - Iterating each column row to create "Configurations"

Tags: c#, for-loop, combinatorics

I've been trying to think the best route to do a loop for this data. I have a table that can be seen below and need to iterate through all column configurations. The column count is dynamic. Results should be:

Apple-Broccoli-Ice Cream
Apple-Broccoli-Pie
Apple-Carrots-Ice Cream
Apple-Carrots-Pie
Apple-Peas-Ice Cream
Apple-Peas-Pie
Apple-Green Beans-Ice Cream
Apple-Green Beans-Pie
Orange-Broccoli-Ice Cream
Orange-Broccoli-Pie
Orange-Carrots-Ice Cream
Orange-Carrots-Pie
Orange-Peas-Ice Cream
Orange-Peas-Pie
Orange-Green Beans-Ice Cream
Orange-Green Beans-Pie

My "manual" code is below, but I would like it to be more dynamic regarding columns (there could be 2,3,5, etc.)

What is the best way to make a dynamic loop when the columns vary?

Note: I have an object "Configuration" and a list of those objects called "configs"

Image of Configuration Table

[image]

```
List<Configuration> configs = new List<Configuration>();

// iterate left to right
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < dataGridConfigTable.Rows.Count - 1; i1++)
{
    string param1 = dataGridConfigTable.Rows[i1].Cells[0].Value.ToString() ?? string.Empty;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param1))
    {
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < dataGridConfigTable.Rows.Count - 1; i2++)
        {
            string param2 = dataGridConfigTable.Rows[i2].Cells[1].Value.ToString() ?? string.Empty;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param2))
            {
                for (int i3 = 0; i3 < dataGridConfigTable.Rows.Count - 1; i3++)
                {
                    string param3 = dataGridConfigTable.Rows[i3].Cells[2].Value.ToString() ?? string.Empty;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param3))
                    {
                        for (int i4 = 0; i4 < dataGridConfigTable.Rows.Count - 1; i4++)
                        {
                            string param4 = dataGridConfigTable.Rows[i4].Cells[3].Value.ToString() ?? string.Empty;

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param4))
                            {
                                for (int i5 = 0; i5 < dataGridConfigTable.Rows.Count - 1; i5++)
                                {
                                    string param5 = dataGridConfigTable.Rows[i5].Cells[4].Value.ToString() ?? string.Empty;

                                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param5))
                                    {
                                        configs.Add(new Configuration(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5));
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Invert your `if`s and use `continue` or `break` as needed to reduce nesting.  That is way too much nesting.

Comment: 10 levels of identations and branches is surely something that needs to be refactored.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @Amy  Isn't "_I would like it [for loops] to be more dynamic regarding columns_" enough for you to know what OP wants?

Comment: Sorry! Totally forgot. I just edited to have the question, but I was wondering if there is a way to make this dynamic with varying column quantities. Thanks!

Comment: So the dataGridConfigTable does not have a `Columns` property? What is the exact type of this object?

Comment: @SeanSullivan it's unclear what exactly the output should be if a 4th column (parameter) existed. I have a good guess, but posting that would make your intent clear.

Comment: I would load all the columns into a 2d string array, then create an index array. If there are 4 columns, your index array starts as {0,0,0,0}. You use that to access the 2d array, print the values and then increment the fourth value in your index array. Repeat until the index _would_ be out of bounds, and then reset it and do the third, then fourth value and so on. I _think_ you could do that in one while loop with some if statements at the end of it to handle your indexes and exit condition. I'm not writing that for you though.

Comment: @Gabriel My comment prompted the OP to improve the quality of the question, which was the point.

Comment: @rufus L it does have a columns property. I’m making a wizard via winforms where in the previous form I declare the column names and quantity. Right now, I have the max at 5, but I still don’t know if the quantity of columns a user wants (parameters) are. They number of columns could be 1-5. My example was just showing that I got a “working version for a set number of columns, but I know this nesting format is not preferred. I know there are better ways, but my knowledge is hitting its peak here. I’m still learning much.

Comment: Can you not just loop through the rows, and then loop through the columns inside the row loop?

Comment: @RufusL That's what I thought I was doing. But all of the loops make for a non-ideal scenario and it's also not dynamic based on the column number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) to produce the final outputs.

So first convert the table (or data source you have) into a list of lists of string, then apply the cartesian product to every list in the collection.

```
    //this function produce the cartesian product of two lists
    List<string> CartesianProduct(List<string> lst1, List<string> lst2, string seperator)
    {
        var res = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < lst1.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < lst2.Count; j++)
            {
                res.Add(lst1[i] + seperator + lst2[j]);
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    //This function apply the cartesian product to all lists
    List<string> CartesianProduct(List<List<string>> lsts, string seperator)
    {
        List<string> res = lsts[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < lsts.Count; i++)
        {
            res = CartesianProduct(res, lsts[i], seperator);
        }
        return res;
    }
```

you might use this method to convert your table into lists

```
       var dt1 = new DataTable(); //your data source
        var lsts = new List<List<string>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            var singleColumnLst = new List<string>();
            for (int j = 0; j < dt1.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                singleColumnLst.Add((string)dt1.Rows[i][j]);
            }
            lsts.Add(singleColumnLst);
        }

        //final results
        var allItems = CartesianProduct(lsts, "-");
```

Comment: Perfect Thank you!

Comment: is there a way to get the output into a list of arrays? Such as ["Apple","Broccoli","Ice Cream"]

Comment: Sure @SeanSullivan, you may create an empty list of arrays and split each item in the final results "allItems" on the separator you choose "," and add the array to the list you create.